# Change size, fill, color in ggplot

Tags: r, ggplot2

I've created a simple scatterplot, with:

```
ggplot(state_im, aes(x = avg_imm_importance, y = vote)) +
      scale_y_continuous(limits =c(0.0, 0.7), breaks = c(0.2, 0.3, 0.4, 
      0.5, 0.6)) +
      scale_x_continuous(limits =c(3.7, 4.4), breaks = c(3.8, 4.0, 4.2, 
      4.4)) +
    geom_point(aes(size = sample_size), col = "#006666", alpha = 0.8) +
    geom_smooth(method = lm, se = FALSE)
```

The problem is, that when I specify:

`geom_point(col = "black" fill = "#006666")` I only get black dots.

I want to change the size of the points manual, so I can make bigger dots for each sample_size, and also the color and fill of the points, so I get color = black, and fill = "#006666".

[image]

Comment: hi, can you provide a [reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example)?

Comment: Compare these two: `ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = "orange", fill = "#006666", size = 5)` and 

`ggplot(mtcars, aes(wt, mpg)) +
  geom_point(color = "orange", fill = "#006666", size = 5, shape = 21)`.  The default shape for `geom_point` (#16) only sees color, not fill. Shape 21 is a point with color defining outline and fill defining the insides. See here: http://www.sthda.com/english/wiki/ggplot2-point-shapes

Comment: I want to both make each point represented by sample size bigger than now AND change fill/col. The problem is when run your solution all of my points has the same size.. How can I fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Try using shape 21, based on Jon's suggestion, along with your previous code, like here. You will get the required size, fill and color

```
ggplot(mtcars,aes(hp,wt,size=disp)) + geom_point(col = "black", fill = "#006666", shape = 21)
```

[image: sample plot]